# Xpath: If inside a node, test to see if it is located inside a certain attribute and if there is another similar node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this xml file

```
<book>
<chapter category="AIRCRAFT">
  <title>Flight Controls</title>
  <section>Bombardier</title>
    <orderedlist>
        <listitem><para>list item 1</para></listitem>
        <listitem><para>list item 2</para></listitem>
        <listitem><para>list item 3</para></listitem>
    </orderedlist>
  </section>
</chapter>

<chapter category="PILOT">
  <title>Flight Operations</title>
  <section>
    <title>Crew Bases</title>
    <orderedlist>
        <listitem><para>list item 1</para></listitem>
        <listitem><para>list item 2
            <note>
                <para>Note: Additional information.</para>
            </note>
            </para>
        </listitem>
        <listitem><para>list item 3</para></listitem>
    </orderedlist>
  </section>
</chapter>

<chapter category="MAINTENANCE">
  <title>Maintenance</title>
  <section>
    <title>Maintenance Bases</title>
    <orderedlist>
        <listitem><para>list item 1</para></listitem>
        <listitem><para>list item 2</para></listitem>
        <listitem><para>list item 3</para></listitem>
    </orderedlist>
  </section>
</chapter>

<chapter category="COMPANY">
  <title>Company Policy Manual</title>
  <section>
    <title>Employment Standards and Eligibility</title>
    <orderedlist>
        <listitem><para>list item 1</para></listitem>
        <listitem><para>list item 2</para></listitem>
        <listitem><para>list item 3</para></listitem>
    </orderedlist>
  </section>
</chapter>

</book>
```

I need to answer these two questions:

1)If inside a para element, test to see if it is located inside the chapter with the category attribute set to “MAINTENANCE”

2)If inside a listitem element, test to see if there is another listitem before it

I need just the statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do (1) using the `ancestor::` axis:

```
ancestor::chapter[1]/@category = 'MAINTENANCE'
```

and (2) using `preceding-sibling::`

```
preceding-sibling::listitem
```

This works if the current context node is a `listitem`, if "inside a listitem element" could include descendant nodes (the `para` element node or the text node inside it) then you'd need something more like

```
ancestor-or-self::listitem[1]/preceding-sibling::listitem
```

(if the current context node is not a `listitem`, go up the tree until you hit one, then from *there*, look if there are any preceding `listitem` siblings)

Comment: Thanks! How would you use them in an if-statement?

Comment: @HillFigga those expressions are suitable as-is to be the `test` of an `xsl:if` - the (1) one is a comparison operation explicitly, the (2) ones return a node set which will be empty (which is treated as false) if there are no preceding listitems and non-empty (treated as true) if there are any.

Comment: @HillFigga however, in many cases you can replace uses of `xsl:if` and `xsl:choose` by refactoring your stylesheet with more specific template match patterns - if you had two templates, one with `match="listitem"` and the other with `match="listitem[1]"` then the specific (`[1]`) one would fire for the first `listitem` in each orderedlist, and the general one would fire for all the others, no need for an explicit `if` test.